# how to hide a buttons on page load using javascript

Tags: phonegap-plugins

Im new to phone gap,developing an app when a i invoke my app for first time in index page one button should display that is configure the Ip address button .once after the configuring the IP Address, that address will be stored in local storage variable. so when i invoke second time of my application,so in index page their is not required of again configure button instead of that i'm checking the condition that stored variable is null nor not.if it is null again first button will display if not means other three  button should display.

how to do that?? i'm not able to hide the button here

Here is my code

```
 HTML:

   <div onload="change">

             <center> <button class="config"  id="config" onclick='return config()'>Configure IP Address</button></center>
             <center><input class="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" value="" ></center>
             <center><input class="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" value=""></center>
             <center><button  id ="LOGIN" class="login" onclick="loginpostactivity()" >Login</button></center>
```

JS:

```
 <script>
                    // Function being used to hide/unhide the button
                  function changeMessage() {
                        if (ipAddress!="") {
                            document.getElementById("config").style.visibility = "visible";
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById("username").style.visibility = "hidden";
                            document.getElementById("password").style.visibility = "hidden";
                            document.getElementById("LOGIN").style.visibility = "hidden";
                        }
                    }
      </script>
```

When i load this page , i want to display the first button if the correct is true, else three button should display .

Answer (score 0):

Perform the two steps below. It probably may solve the issue.

1. Make the uname pwd and login button hidden in `if` block
2. Make the config button visible in `else` block.